# How to change CSS properties of a page using dynamic URL building with Express?

Tags: javascript, express, pug, dynamic-url

Let's say there is an element and I need to simply change the color property:

```
<p id='text'>COLOR</p>

<script>
document.getElementById('text').style.color = "red";
</script>
```

How can I achieve this by using the dynamic route parameter described [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_url_building.htm), for example

```
http://localhost:3000/colors/blue
```

would make the style.color property of text element, blue.

```
app.get('/template/:color', function(req, res){
  res.render('view', {
    text: MyText 
    //change css property of 'text' using 'color' url parameter
  });
 });
```

How can I change the `style.color` property of a DOM element using Express URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express or server in general cannot modify css properties.

Personally I would make a condition directly in the frontend.

For example:

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;

if(urlPath === "/colors/blue"){
     document.getElementById('text').style.color = "red";
}
```